# Why capacitor 3 loses energy as it induces current in other capacitors

Tags: capacitor, electrostatic

[image]

plate B of capacitor 1 and 2 are connected to capacitor 3 to provide potential difference. Part A includes capacitor plate and dielectric.

When part A and B are connected the positive charges will be repelled from capacitor 1 through load to capacitor 2 and negative charges will be attracted from 2 to 1.

When A and B are separated potential difference will be removed from parts A of capacitor 1 and 2 so parts A will both neutralize.

The reason I use three capacitors in this setup is I don’t want charge to flow from capacitor 3 through load but induce it through capacitors 1 and 2 when plates A and B are connected and separated. So I expect capacitor 3 not to lose energy fast.
After contacting plates A to B of capacitors 1 and 2 and separating them at intervals of 1 second. The energy in capacitor 3 reduces over time so current flowing into load reduces. One of the reason I think causes this is I do this not in a vacuum so charge escapes when dielectric is disconnected from plate B and exposed to air. Resistance as charge flows from plate B back to capacitor when plates are disconnected. Which other way so you think makes energy to be lost from capacitor 3 as it induces current through capacitors 1 and 2.

Comment: Have you calculated how much energy is lost as heat in the load?

Comment: You also lose energy in the wires/connections from C3 and from the ESR of all the caps.

Comment: Every time you change the structure of the setup, current flows.  Since C3 is the only charged component at the start, moving things around causes current to flow from C3 to the other parts.  Energy is disippated in the load.  Where's the mystery?

Comment: @JRE when A is connected to B the charges flow to plates B from capacitor 3. when plates are disconnected they flow back to capacitor 3